# Поиск #define-директив в .cpp файле

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Здравствуйте. В .cpp исходнике нужно выдрать все `#define`, и, так как `#define` может занимать несколько строк, не могу построить правильный regexp. На данный момент такой вариант (не находит если более 3-х строк):

```
#d.*?(?(?=\\\r?\n)(.*?\n.*?\n)|\n)+
```

Comment: отдельно получалось выделить однострочный и многострочный паттерн, но лень писать выражение. теоретически многострочный паттерн состоит из первой строки без знака '\' и нескольких частей которые отвечают за сивол переноса строки и следую строчку дефайна: `(\\$^.*)`

Comment: Вы уверены, что задача сформулирована полно ?

Про комментарии не забыли ? Вообще-то, в общем случае про \#ifdef-ы тоже подумать надо.

IMHO тут regexp-ы не работают.

Comment: Задача сформулирована полно. То, о чем Вы говорите, уже сделано.

Comment: @avp не надо так о регэкспах. На них в vim'е вся подсветка синтаксиса сделана.

Comment: @alexlz, если регэкспы так просты, то почему люди постоянно путаются в них (и задают вопросы) ? 

Если данная задача сформулирована полно, то она решается на Си максимум за полчаса (и без вопросов).

Comment: А вот об их простоте я не писал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет ничего невозможного.
[Атомарная группировка, или Ни шагу назад!](http://habrahabr.ru/post/56765/)

Comment: Сильно.

Особенно понравился комментарий:

    Когда-то на ночь от бессоницы предлагался учебник по квантовой физике, теперь же достаточно ограничиться вечерним разбором вхоядщего смс-сообщения с использованием регэкспов. Крепкий сон, титул извращенца и стул в руки будут у вас непременно.

Answer (score 3):

Постарался учесть все возможные аспекты написания дефайнов:

1. Перед # может быть любое число пробелов, табов и экранированных переносов строк.
2. Аналогично между # и define
   Скрин что примерно получилось:
   [image: screen]
   Само регулярное выражение:

   ```
   $RE = <<< HEREDOC
   ^ # начало строки или текста
   (?P<probel>
       (?:
           [ \\t] | # пробелы, табуляция или
           \\\\     # обратный слэш, за ним
           \\r?     # возможно \r
           \\n      # и \n
       )*+
   )
   [#]
   (?P>probel) # хоть такая ссылка и называется рекурсивной, рекурсии фактически нет
   define(?=[^a-z0-9_]|\$) # define справа от которого не символ или конец строки
                           # грамматика требует уточнения
   (?:
       \\\\[^\\r\\n] | # что-то экранированное, но не переводы строк, или
       \\\\\\r?\\n   | # экранированный перевод строки, или
       [^\\r\\n]       # любой символ кроме перевода строки
   )*+
   \$ # конец строки или текста

   HEREDOC;

   echo preg_replace("/$RE/xum", "<span style='color:white;background-color:blue'>$0</span>", $text);
   ```

Живой пример на [IDEone](http://ideone.com/HWgntr).
Буду рад замечаниям. Я кстати не знаю что может быть справа от define. Предполагаю, что это все что угодно, кроме `[a-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Не забывайте о комментариях :-) http://ideone.com/wGjcFY

Comment: @VladD, если учитывать комментарии и содержание строк, то это уже почти полный парсер с++ получится :)  
Поэтому я их пожалуй пропущу.

Comment: Ну так :-) У вас ведь где-то есть парсер комментариев, я помню. (Вот ещё: <http://ideone.com/4USVwo>.)

Comment: @VladD, здесь:  
http://ideone.com/n9jb4k  
Поиск дефайнов с учетом строк, комментариев однострочных и многострочных. char кажется, никак не могут повлиять, поэтому их не делал.  
Вы опять сподвигли меня заниматься безумием :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: Хм, вот такое вроде покамест проходит: <http://ideone.com/H0K0AI>. Но всё равно круто. Может, стоит выложить скелет парсера на [исследования@хэшкод](http://hashcode.ru/research/)?

Comment: В самом деле, @ReinRaus, опубликовали бы на ***Исследованиях*** цикл лекций по программированию с помощью регулярок. 

А там, глядишь и остальные пописали бы реализации более-менее законченных примеров на разных языках.

Могла бы полезная для всех тема, действительно в духе базы знаний, получиться.

Answer (score 1):

На этот вопрос [отвечали на стеке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424458/regular-expression-to-match-cs-multiline-preprocessor-statements).

Для тех, кто не любит ходить по ссылкам:

```
'(?m)^#define (?:.*\\\r?\n)*.*$'
```

Сам не проверял, пишут, что должно работать для конструкций типа

```
#define max(a,b) \
       ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
           typeof (b) _b = (b); \
         _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Comment: Только вот в программе перед '#' и между '#' и define могут быть пробелы, табуляции и экранированные NL. 

Например такая фигня

       \
  #  \
\
 define \
   xaxa \
22 \

main ()
{
  printf ("%d\n",xaxa);
}


компилируется и работает.

Comment: Ну, тест на пробелы как раз не проблема добавить. Грамматика останется регулярной.

Comment: Возможно. А приведенный регэксп #include заодно не выбросит ?

Я вообще не доверяю программам с более-менее сложной логикой, завязанной на регэкспы. В большинстве случаев они с ошибками, которые редко проявляются и следовательно никогда не отлаживаются.

Comment: Нет, не работает. Работает только для указанных конструкций (и то, только после добавления ? перед $)

Comment: @avp, по условиям задачи, #include не нужен. Только #define. Что касается опасности регулярных выражений, тут просто нужно хорошее покрытие тестами.
@Weikedo, приведите примеры дефайнов. Про дополнительные пробелы я написал, их нужно дополнительно отслеживать. Что там у вас еще встречается?

Comment: Дефайны могут быть абсолютно любые. От одной линии, до примера, который был показан товарищем avp.
Думаю, стоит попробовать способ со срезанием строк. Спасибо!

Comment: @Weikedo, если Вы пишете на С, а \#ifdef-ы и строковые константы Вас не волнуют, то зачем Вам регэкспы ? 

Тут программа строк на 20 из stdin в stdout.

Comment: В общем, это дело с помощью regex не решается, ибо рекурсия. Поступил простым склеиванием мультилайновых дефайнов. 
avp,задача, изначально, была совершенно другой.